# How to set the default value of a BLOB column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, blob, default-value

Is it possible to automatically assigned the value of a `BLOB` column in **MySQL** without uploading a file everytime a new line is included?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `DEFAULT` value clause in a **data type** specification indicates a **default value** for a column.

Nevertheless `BLOB` and `TEXT` columns **cannot be assigned** a default value.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html